# Can docker service scale the swarm it is in?

Tags: docker, containers, docker-swarm, orchestration

I need a custom monitor application running in my docker swarm, which has logic to decide whether I want to create more instances of another worker application running in the swarm. Is it possible for my monitoring service to tell the swarm to add new instances of my worker application?

Eg: 
Initial state: swarm -> 1 Monitor + 3 Worker
monitor realizes it needs 4 workers now and asks swarm to add an instance.
Final state: swarm -> 1 Monitor + 4 Worker

(p.s. all workers are of the same image)

Comment: "worker application" = docker service, "worker application instance" = docker container ?

Comment: both are services.

Comment: I don't understand, how can an instance of a service be a service?

Comment: Okay, let me rephrase, I'm new to docker so my terminology might be weak.
I have two different service's instances
A montior service instanc
And multiple worker service instances